# Is there a way to somehow put an if else statement in the Cucumber test steps for a scenario that previously didn't have one?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, ui-automation, gherkin, cucumber-java

So the problem is as follows.

Previously the SUT I worked on had only one button to "refund" the offer. However, for legal reasons, the "refund" button is available only 20 days after the offer creation. After that, the refund button is replaced with the "cancel" button. Apart from that, there previously was also a cancel button next to the refund button which is now gone. Now there is only one button which is first "refund" and after 20 days "cancel".

There are currently two scenarios that we use:

```
  Scenario: Verify that a user can refund an offer
    Given I login into the system if I am not already logged in
    Given I navigate to the system back office page
    And I click on the offers tab in the system
    And I navigate to the last active offer page 
    And I should see the offer page
    And I should see the status "Paid" for the last offer in the system
    When I refund the offer
    Then I should see the status "Open" for the last offer in the system

  Scenario: Verify that a user is able to cancel an offer
    Given I navigate to the offer page
    And I click on the offers tab in the system
    And I navigate to the last active offer page 
    And I should see the system offer page
    And I should see the status "Open" for the last offer in the system
    When I click on the cancel offer button in the system
    And I should see the cancellation reason page in the system
    And I select a random reason for the last offer in the system
    And I should see the system offer page
    Then I should see the status "Cancelled" for the last offer in the system
```

Could you please give me some advice on how to go around the current issue, because the tests are failing randomly, because sometimes, depending on the offer, either one or the other button is visible? What would be the best way to overcome this?

Comment: Make it as 1 scenario in the feature file - check that condition in the step definition file.

Comment: The problem is, this is automation legacy code, and the tests are end to end, so in the system an inquiry with the id is used and then the offer also with the id, that means there is a static thing with one id and one date, which is random in the future, so it may be less than 20 days and more than that. This is why I would need somehow one scenario and if else within the steps java class(which is not a problem) but how do I put this in Gherkin in one scenario, where there is no when else or if else.

Comment: You have been given a system that isn't testable. You have to change the system to make it testable. This is one of the many reasons developers should be involved in the creation of tests.

Answer (score 0):

Gherkin doesn't support if-statements. It is up to the testers and to create a system that can be tested in an automated fashion. Currently this doesn't appear to be the case.

Fixing this properly may be an organisational problem - test automation is an engineering challenge that can not be solved by individuals. And that's out of scope for StackOverflow.

However what you can do is skip a scenario if a certain precondition isn't met.

We check this pre-condition by adding an extra step. Normally you would use this to create an (non-)refundable offer, now we'll only check it.

```
  Scenario: Verify that a user can refund an offer
   Given a refundable offer
...

Scenario: Verify that a user is able to cancel an offer
    Given a non-refundable offer
...
```

Cucumber supports OpenTest4Js `TestAbortedException`. This makes it possible to use JUnit Jupiters `Assumptions` to abort rather than fail a scenario.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions;

@Given("a refundable offer")
public void verify_offer_is_refundable(){
    boolean condition = // decide if tests should abort because the offer is not refundable 
    Assumptions.assumeTrue(condition, "Offer was not refundable");
}
```

The same also works with JUnit 4s `Assumption` class and TestNGs `SkipException`.

Having a skipped test will look ugly in your reports but